# Minimum IIS version for ASP.NET Core

Tags: asp.net, iis, iis-7, asp.net-core

On a windows server 2008 R2 with IIS  7 installed, will I be able to install an ASP.NET core application

From https://github.com/aspnet/IISIntegration/issues/105 i read that AspNetCoreModule v0.8 is based on a fork of HttpPlatformHandler 1.2.

However I was unable to install HttpPlatformHandler on IIS 7.

Comment: Have you tried installing IIS 7.5? https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc771209(v=ws.11).aspx

Comment: Yes 2008 R2 is supported. Have you tried it yet?

Comment: Yes, it works on 2008 R2, got it on production with several ASP.Net Core App hosted in IIS. Install bundle from this page https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/servers/aspnet-core-module?tabs=aspnetcore2x